# Library functions not found when compiling Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c, ubuntu, linker, clang, undefined-reference

I have my own library with some basic functions inside which I compile using `ar rcs *a few .o files*`

Now I'm in a project where I have to use this library the code is basic :

```
#include "libft.h"

int main()
{
    ft_putstr_fd("test", 1);
    return (0);
}
```

I create the binary file using this command `clang -fsanitize=address -ILIBFT/includes/ -c test.c -o test.o`
And when trying to make the final executable file I get this and I don't understand why... Does it have something to do with the fact that I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 ?

Here's the command when I create the executable file `clang -fsanitize=address -ILIBFT/includes/ -L LIBFT -lft -o test test.o` 
And here's the output :

```
/usr/bin/ld: test.o: in function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `ft_putstr_fd'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The function does is defined in `libft.h` as it works on my school's iMac.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: That post mentions gcc but it is the same for clang.

Comment: Thank you so much @kaylum I had no idea that the order mattered !

Comment: No ned to keep the images after you added the text version.